# isolate scope within directive doesn't behave as expected

Tags: angularjs

I'm creating a test directive as can be seen here:

http://jsbin.com/xosusozipufe/1/

This isn't behaving as expected. I thought the h4 within the directive div would read 'within the app Hello World' on load and then the end would change as the buttons were clicked. The html nested within the directive div doesn't inherit the isolate scope of the directive, is this correct?

Any thoughts appreciated

C

Answer (score 0):

- @ isolated scope is one way and works in up-down fashion that means whatever you pass that will go as string so you can not update from scope of directive.
- Either you should use transclude or put html of directive inside template/templateUrl option.
- If you want update from directive scope then either you can use "=" isolated scope or you can pass function with "&" isolated scope.

[**JSBin Demo**](http://jsbin.com/xosusozipufe/2/edit)